# i have no oil and only have butter is it ok to use it

Tags: substitutions

So basically I have butter but not oil and need 100 ml of oil .Is it okay if use 100 g of butter?If not whats the best thing to do?

Comment: What is the recipe?

Comment: Butter is about 75% fat, so either use 100ml of *clarified* butter, or about 130ml of whole butter.